# How to stop/prevent screenshots and screen Recordings in react native or mobile apps

Tags: android, react-native

> hey I have solution about this
> > >how to stop screenshots and recording in your app
> >>paste this code and the screenshots and recording stops in your app

Answer (score 0):

```
>/android/app/src/main/java/com/{Project_Name}/MainActivity.java
>>import android.view.WindowManager;
>>>@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```